# How to resolve "ImportError while loading conftest" while running through jenkins job. But working fine in local

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, automated-tests, pytest

I am trying to run my tests through Jenkins using **pytest** framework and facing the below error.

```
C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Project1>pytest -s -v test_cases\ 
ImportError while loading conftest 'C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Project1\test_cases\conftest.py'.
test_cases\conftest.py:4: in <module>
    from chromedriver_py import binary_path
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chromedriver_py'
```

**Note: But when I run tests locally, all tests are working fine.**

My project structure

```
ProjectName
      configurations
      logs
      page_objects
          tc_1_page_obj.py
          tc_2_page_obj.py
      test_cases
          test_case1.py
          test_case2.py
          conftest.py
      utilities
      testdata
```

**contents in conftest.py**

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from chromedriver_py import binary_path

service_object = Service(executable_path=binary_path)
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def driver():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service_object, 
    options=options)
    driver.maximize_window()
    return driver
```

**Jenkins pipline**
pipenv shell
pytest -s -v test_cases\

Comment: `chromedriver_py` is not installed in your jenkins ci environment